# Crossroads.js and require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to use crossroads.js with require.js to determine what file to require based on the URL.

I have crossroads set as a dependancy in a Router.js file and if I console.log(crossroads) straight out from the crossroads.js file I get the crossroads object. However it isnt getting passed to the Router.js file, its null or undefined... Wonder if anyone has had this issue before?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: somehow I only saw your comment on my blog today... sorry about that.

Comment: Im actually having the same problem just now. Found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Crossroads.js works with RequireJS since the beginning (I use RequireJS on all my projects) you probably had some misconfiguration on your paths or expected the global `crossroads` var to be exposed (which doesn't happen on an AMD environment) or maybe crossroads was being loaded before RequireJS (which would skip the AMD `define` process).